# Heroku Name is invalid when deploy Docker image? How to debug?

Tags: java, docker, debugging, heroku

I created a `Docker` image for `Spring Boot` app.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=target/demo-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} demo-app.jar

# Run the jar file 
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/demo-app.jar"]
```

I followed [Heroku official docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime).

Pushed it `heroku container:push appshub/demo-app`.

Released it `heroku container:release appshub/demo-app`.

During the release I always get the same error:

> Releasing images appshub/demo-app to trata-ololo-35436305... !
>
> ▸  Name is invalid

I found [Deploy Existing Docker Image To Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127765/deploy-existing-docker-image-to-heroku) and [Heroku docker deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807796/heroku-docker-deployment) that don't work for me and searching in the official docs or the web doesn't help either.

How to debug this issue?

Comment: Try to remove the slash in `appshub/demo-app`. It seems that's a known issue [container:push allows names that cannot be used with container:release](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/932)

Comment: @b0gusb Can you add it as an answer? I couldn't find the answer to it, so I assume that I wouldn't be alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the slash in `appshub/demo-app`. It seems that's a known issue [container:push allows names that cannot be used with container:release](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/932)

Push/release, are setting a process type name and not an image tag name. See section [Building and pushing images](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime).
A process type name can't have a `/`.

Hope that helps.